# What causes the descriptive text in HTTPS lock icons?

Tags: tls, web

Some websites have descriptive text next to their lock icon. [image: HTTPS Lock for LastPass.com displays LogMeIn, Inc.]

While many other websites (like Google) simply display a simple green lock icon.

What causes this? And does this text have a special name?

Answer (score 6):

That's called [Extended Validation Certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate).